# Small layout adjustments for iPhone 6/plus etc

Tags: ios, autolayout

I set layout in storyboard to adjust dynamically to screen size.

Among other things, I set an image to scale proportionally to the size superview (match width and height with a 0.9 constant). Now, on the iPhone 6 and 6 plus the image looks a bit too big. So for these screens I would like to set the constant to 0.8. Maybe also I would like to set a bit bigger font size.

So far I read the size classes are not usable for this, as there's only 1 class for all iPhones portrait. And I'm not going to create a new storyboard only to change a constant...

Is there a way to do this in the storyboard? Or do I have to check screen size programmatically ( :( )?

If doing it programmatically is the only way, what is the recommended way to do it?

Comment: Instead of Setting the width and height, you can set the trailing/ bottom property for different size classes and set the corresponding constant.

Comment: But as I wrote size classes are not usable for this, as far I understand. There's no way to differentiate between e.g. iPhone 5 portrait and iPhone 6 plus portrait using size classes.

Comment: One thought: If you are worried about the image becoming too large, then have you tried adding a width constraint (where width <= 150 points for example) to stop the image growing past a certain size?

Comment: Yeah, then no other go , but code. You would have to check the scaling factor in code or machine version (5,6, etc). May be using #Define and place the if_else blocks. If u r using swift, you can override some operator to take two values on above condition.

Comment: Why do you say it looks too big? There might be a way to express mathematically what is your criteria for sizing the image... can you be more specific about this?

Answer (score 0):

If you can define the max width (and/or height) with a constant value, than you could put a higher-priority constraint with a "less than or equals" value. So if the max width it looks good is about 315, make the "equal widths * 0.9" constraint lower priority than a constraint "less than or equals to 315".

2) If using Layout Constraints programmatically, the best way is to update in the View Controller's updateViewConstraints. There are a couple techniques, but the simplest for these requirements is "default, and lower-priority non-default."

1. Create the constraints in IB for the "default" behavior, and then create contradictory constraints in IB for non default behavior. Set the contradictory constraints to a lower priority. This should produce warnings while you're doing it but have no warnings at the end, just some dotted line constraints.
2. Create outlets for the default constraints to the view controller. Call these "`pictureDefaultWidthConstraint`" and "`pictureDefaultHeightConstraint`".
3. In `updateViewConstraints` of the View Controller, set the default constraints active or inactive based on the desired behavior:

   ```
   -(void)updateViewConstraints {

   BOOL useDefaultSizes = YES;
   if (self.view.frame.size.width > 320) {
       useDefaultSizes = NO;
   }

   self.pictureDefaultWidthConstraint.active = useDefaultSizes;
   self.pictureDefaultHeightConstraint.active = useDefaultSizes;

   [super updateViewConstraints];
   }
   ```

Of course when the default constraints are set inactive, the lower-priority non-default constraints kick in. You can set other conditions, such as cascading series of defaults. Keeping it to a series of constraints that are activated based on boolean programmatic tests keeps it testable and straightforward.